Identifying Obfuscation Tools and Effective Deobfuscation Methods
I am currently working on my university graduation project which involves reverse engineering a malware sample. This project requires me to analyze and reverse engineer the malware.
Project Overview:
Objective: Reverse engineer and analyze the malware to understand its behavior and potentially identify the obfuscation techniques used.
Tools Used: dnSpy for initial inspection, and de4dot for deobfuscation.
Current Challenge: The malware appears to be heavily obfuscated. De4dot detects an "Unknown Obfuscator" and encounters several errors during the deobfuscation process, such as ResolutionScope is null and Instruction operand is null.
Questions:
How can I identify the obfuscation tool used on this malware? Are there specific signatures or patterns in the code that can point to a particular obfuscation tool?
What are the best tools and methods for deobfuscating .NET executables, especially when dealing with complex or unknown obfuscators?
Any guidance or recommendations on approaches to take, additional tools to use, or specific techniques to apply would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance.
